# TCP Client Spring Integration with Legacy Server

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration, tcpclient

I need some help with a migration to Spring Integration.
Actually we have a component based in java.net package, it includes only a few classes with a java classic TCP Client, nothing fancy, that actually works to send some requests to a legacy server by tcp. This is the code for sending and receiving a message:

```
public String sendMessage(String info) {

    try {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(info);

        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

        return br.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

The problem is that I want to start using Spring Integration in the client side, but I cannot change the server because it belongs to another company, but I don't receive the response from the server, I tried a lot of configuration and no luck at all.
This is my client configuration right now:

```
            <int:gateway id="gw"
                 service-interface="pe.financieraoh.core.cointegrador.tcp.SimpleGateway"
                 default-request-channel="input"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="localhost"
                                   port="7777"
                                   single-use="false"
                                   serializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
                                   deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
                                    />
    <int:channel id="input" />

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
                                 request-channel="input"
                                 reply-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
                                 connection-factory="client"
                                 request-timeout="10000"
                                 reply-timeout="10000" />

<bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" 
          class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer"/>

<int:object-to-string-transformer id="clientBytes2String"
                                      input-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel" />
```

I tried a lot and always received a TimeOutConnection Exception, I'm pretty sure the server did not receive my request, but I cannot be sure, because I dont have access to the server logs. My only guide is the legacy code in the client works fine.
Thanks for your help.

Here is the logs from the server, i tried several kind of de/serializer with the same result, 2020-06-21 23:47:10.377 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway : Tcp Gateway exception org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:243) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.3.0.RELEASE.jar:5.3.0.RELEASE]

Comment: Please update the question with logs instead of posting in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the equivalent of `println` and `readLine` you need a `ByteArrayLfSerializer` (if running the client on Linux/Unix/Mac) or the default `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` (if running the client on Windows).

If that doesn't work, use WireShark or similar to look at the network traffic.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your answer, I had no luck with the serializer i will try to see what going on with wireshark but i need to check how to do that because the conection is between two servers, and i cannot access the tcp server from my local computer.

Comment: You don't need to; you can run wireshark on the client machine to capture the network traffic. One other possibility is the server is closing the socket to signal the end (instead of CRLF, or LF). In that case, try a `ByteArrayRawDeserializer`.

Comment: Great, yes i will use a sidecard tcpdump in openshift to capture the traffic, i think tomorrow i will get more info, meanwhile i will try the ByteArrayRawDeserializer, really thanks again Gary

Comment: Hi again i could check with a tcpdump and wireshark that the configuration works fine, i have another problem, there is like a firewall or a gateway system, that is filtering the communication with the external server, but i cant tell, why is that. the message is receive fine in the gateway but is not receiving in the final system, for that reason i get a "Timeout Exception"  i will check with Operation or DevOps. thanks again Gary for your help